# Thymeleaf: wrong url with jquery

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the below form, i used jquery to submit the form

```
<form id="msform" th:action="@{/pay/{id}(id = ${requestNumber})}" th:object="${otpRequest}" method="POST">
    ....
    <input id="submit-form" type="button" class="next action-button" value="Valider"/>
</form>

<script>
  $('#submit-form').on('click', function () {
    var form = $('#msform');
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function (result) {
        // Do something with the response.
        // Might want to check for errors here.
      }, error: function (error) {
        // Here you can handle exceptions thrown by the server or your controller.
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class PopupResource {

@GetMapping("{requestNumber}")
String popup(@PathVariable String requestNumber, Model model) {}

@PostMapping("pay/{requestNumber}")
public String pay(@PathVariable String requestNumber, @ModelAttribute("otpRequest") @Valid OTPRequest otpRequest, Model model) {}

}
```

when submit the form i get an error 404, because the url which triggers is `http://localhost:9096/pay/f2399544-2f2d-47c5-be1a-908b391f5214` instead of `http://localhost:9096/user/pay/f2399544-2f2d-47c5-be1a-908b391f5214`

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: In your case, you have a button inside the form, therefore that button causes the form to be submitted using the standard form submission process. Your Ajax method is not called. If you want to use Ajax to submit the form data, then move the submit button outside the form (at which point I don't think there is any value in having a `<form>` at all).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting relative url for your ajax request.
In your specific case, the relative url that you extract using this line of code:

```
form.attr('action')
```

will be `/pay/{id}`.

So if your current address is in this form:

```
protocol://some.domain.name/relativeUrl
```

Then your ajax request will be sent to :

```
protocol://some.domain.name/pay/{id}
```

which is what you see.

If you replace this line of code:

```
th:action="@{/pay/{id}(id = ${requestNumber})}"
```

with this:

```
 th:action="@{/user/pay/{id}(id = ${requestNumber})}"
```

It should work as expected.